# How do you understend "да нет наверно"?

Tags: значения

How to understend "да нет наверно" like an unswer ?

> - Будешь чай ?
> - Да нет наверно....

Comment: this is not a duplicate Да нет and Да нет наверн is is different mining in rus

Comment: I agree with a3code, this is not exactly a duplicate of that question, however I also agree with @shabunc in that they are similar.

Comment: The closest English translation of this phrase is "well, probably, no".

Comment: "Да нет наверное" is exactly the same thing as "probably да нет", so this question boils down to "да нет" question. The answer to the question, which I'm insisting to be a dup, is a 100% complete answer to this question. *Moreover*, one of the answers provided there covers exactly this issue: 

> It means "No". There is also phrase "Да нет, наверное"."

Comment: Nope, Да нет, наверное = yes in case you have good mood, and = no in case bad mood. + sometimes it is possible to say add наверное  when you change your first part of point of view during answer and answer Да нет

Comment: In this case, "да" doesn't mean "yes". It is a particle meaning not being sure, like "Well,.." . "Наверное" means "probably", "I think". So, this phrase is a very unsure form of NO. Something like "Well... I think, no...". "Да нет" means NO as well, but it is a strong form. Usually it is used when one person cannot understand something, and another corrects him in an emotional nervous way. Example: -"Значит, он вчера сюда не приходил?" "Да нет, приходил! Просто не сказал никому об этом." TRanslation: "So, he didn't come here yesterday?" "Yes, he did! He just didn't tell anybody about it"

Comment: Well, maybe this last example is a bit confusing, but what I'M trying to get acroos is the fact that "Да нет" and "Да нет, наверное" both mean NO, but they have very different emotional color and are used in different situations. Since the emotional part in Russian language is important (yes, our language is very emotional 8) ), I don't consider these two phrases equal, so it is not a duplicate question.